# Change Jquery TimePicker Theme Dynamically

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-timepicker

I'm currently using jQuery Timepicker in my page.

I want to use the same TimePicker on another page but I want to change the theme to 'smoothness`

How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

If it's a different page then you just need to change the stylesheet on the other page to your new theme URL:

```
<link href="NEW THEME URL" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
```